# Prediction from a Deployed SCIKITLEARN model at Google Cloud ML-Engine

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction, google-cloud-ml

I have created a ml model for fraud detection as:

A little snippet of the actual model code as:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor

# define a random state
state = 1

# define the outlier detection method
classifiers = {
    "Isolation Forest": IsolationForest(max_samples=len(X),
                                       contamination=outlier_fraction,
                                       random_state=state),
    "Local Outlier Factor": LocalOutlierFactor(
    n_neighbors = 20,
    contamination = outlier_fraction)
}
import pickle
# fit the model
n_outliers = len(Fraud)

for i, (clf_name, clf) in enumerate(classifiers.items()):

    # fit te data and tag outliers
    if clf_name == "Local Outlier Factor":
        y_pred = clf.fit_predict(X)
        # Export the classifier to a file
        with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as model_file:
            pickle.dump(clf, model_file)
        scores_pred = clf.negative_outlier_factor_
    else:
        clf.fit(X)
        scores_pred = clf.decision_function(X)
        y_pred = clf.predict(X)
        # Export the classifier to a file
        with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as model_file:
            pickle.dump(clf, model_file)

    # Reshape the prediction values to 0 for valid and 1 for fraudulent
    y_pred[y_pred == 1] = 0
    y_pred[y_pred == -1] = 1

    n_errors = (y_pred != Y).sum()

    # run classification metrics 
    print('{}:{}'.format(clf_name, n_errors))
    print(accuracy_score(Y, y_pred ))
    print(classification_report(Y, y_pred ))
```

I have created a storage bucket, ml model, and a version successfully on Google Cloud Platform.
But as a beginner to ml world, I'm confused, how I can pass the input to this model to get a real prediction as this model is deployed on Google's ML-Engine now.

> Update: As stated in the N3da's answer, now I'm using this code for online prediction:

```
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

PROJECT_ID = "PROJECT_ID"
VERSION_NAME = "VERSION"
MODEL_NAME = "MODEL_NAME"
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
name = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(PROJECT_ID, MODEL_NAME)
name += '/versions/{}'.format(VERSION_NAME)

data = {
    "instances": [
      [265580, 7, 68728, 8.36, 4.76, 84.12, 79.36, 3346, 1, 11.99, 1.14,
        655012, 0.65, 258374, 0, 84.12],
    ]
}

response = service.projects().predict(
    name=name,
    body={'instances': data}
).execute()

if 'error' in response:
  print (response['error'])
else:
  online_results = response['predictions']
  print(online_results)
```

But it returns access error as:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/models/MODEL_NAME/versions/VERSION:predict?alt=json returned "Access to model denied.">

Help me, please!

Comment: Can you verify that the model exists in the gcs bucket and it's accessible to your user?

Additional (and unrelated) note: In the above code you can probably just do: `data = [[265580, 7, 68728, 8.36, 4.76, 84.12, 79.36, 3346, 1, 11.99, 1.14,655012, 0.65, 258374, 0, 84.12] ]`

the `"instances"` key gets added a few lines below (`body={'instances': data}`) so you don't need to have it twice.

Comment: Please see n3das update below

Comment: Hi @rhaertel80, you are right, I have updated my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have successfully created a `Version`, you can either use `gcloud` tool or send http requests to get online predictions. From [this](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/getting-predictions#get_online_predictions), here is an example of sending http requests from python code:

```
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
name = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(PROJECT_ID, MODEL_NAME)
name += '/versions/{}'.format(VERSION_NAME)

response = service.projects().predict(
    name=name,
    body={'instances': data}
).execute()

if 'error' in response:
    print (response['error'])
else:
  online_results = response['predictions']
```

`data` in the above example would be a list where each element is an instance that your model accepts. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/v1/predict-request#request-body) is more info about the prediction request and response.

Update: 
For the permission issue you mentioned, it would help to know how/where you created the model and versions from initially (via gcloud, UI console, on your laptop, etc.) The error message suggests that your user has access to your project, but *not* the model. Try running `gcloud auth login` from wherever you are running your python code and confirm that the project it shows as the default project matches your PROJECT_ID.

Comment: Hi @N3da, can you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50013828/7644562 , please?

Comment: answered (hopefully)